# Eagle chain B-gap adjustment without plastic tool

Tags: derailleur-rear, sram

SRAM makes [this plastic tool](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B01N233O4D) for adjusting the B-gap on their Eagle derailleurs. My question is, if I want to measure this distance without this tool (say with a caliper instead), how should I go about it? Between which two points should I make the measurement and what's the value I should aim for?

Comment: Standard B-screw adjustment is to get a gap of 5-6 mm between the tips of the teeth of the largest sprocket and upper idler, measured with a 5 or 6mm hex wrench. The Eagle tool seems to leave a [bigger gap](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=YjgBtCObYDY). Perhaps someone with a tool can measure the tooth-tip gap.

Comment: The 'progressive-degressive' method might help. Turn to the maximum gap. then slowly and carefully reduce by half or quarter turns until it gets sub-optimal. This bit I forgot: then go back that last bit. Never had problems with any bike that way. (I won't take liability for this.)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This measurement is given by both Shimano and SRAM as the shortest distance between the circles formed by the tips of the teeth of the largest cog and those of the guide pulley.

The spec for Eagle is 15mm.

A simple way of actually doing it is to hold up a 15mm wrench, caliper, track nut, etc to it.

Give it a little fine tuning once the chain is on and you're setting up the shifting. You'll be able to tell how small changes (1/4 turn-ish) have some bearing on how smoothly and quietly it all works.

Comment: Wow - 15mm is quite a large gap.  I've run some shimano ones at about 0mm difference!

Comment: I can only tell it makes a difference on whether the chain engages correctly with the largest cog or if its teeth stay aligned more with the rollers of the links. I suspect I have other problems like a bent hanger because I can't get it to shift right both on both ends of the cassette at the same time.

Comment: Yeah, bent hanger sounds likely.

Comment: I would add the chain should be on the second largest cog, not on the largest one.

Answer (score 2):

the gap is 15mm with the suspension at 30% sag

Comment: Welcome to Stackexchange - please browse the [tour] and see how the site is organised, and thank you for your contribution - feel free to try some other questions too.